# How to execute HTTP GET method with cookie value filled?

Tags: java, http

My problem is that I want to use Java to implement an application which sends an HTTP GET request to some website. However, the target website needs one cookie to be set:

```
Country=US
```

If this cookie is null it returns bad indications. My question is how I can set the cookie value before I use `openConnection()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `URLConnection` and add a `Cookie` header:

http://www.hccp.org/java-net-cookie-how-to.html

```
URL myUrl = new URL("http://www.yourserver.com/path");
URLConnection urlConn = myUrl.openConnection();
urlConn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", "Country=US");
urlConn.connect();
```

Comment: Yes, I did these and after that I use BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
     BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream())); to get the content, but I get null. What could be the fault?

Answer (score 0):

You can place the cookie your self by adding a header, or use a higher level HTTP library like [Apache's HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/) which API includes cookies handling features.